# Traversing the result of $.get() with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, traversal

I load some HTML via $.get(); I only want some parts of the result inserted into my html. So searched SO found [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034996/jquery-traverse-html-result-of-geturl-functiondata) and then tried this:

```
$("a.load").click(function() {
  $.get(this.href, {}, function(result) {
    content = $("#main", result);
    console.log(content);
  }, "html");
  return false;
});
```

Though `result` has the correct contents `console.log(content)` returns `[]`. Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what `console.log(result)` outputs?

Comment: It the whole html in a string of the requested page. Nothing special about that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to do what it sounds like you are, [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) would be easier:

```
$("a.load").click(function() {
  $("#WhereYouWantHTMLInjected").load(this.href + ' #main');

  return false;
});
```

Comment: This is the reason one simply hast to love jQuery. :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

The line `content = $("#main", result);` seems wrong. The second argument of a plain jQuery statement is scope -- you are giving it html and I suspect it doesn't know what to do with that. It gives back an empty jQuery array.

If you want to use jQuery to parse the resulting html, you have to add it to an element, then operate on it. So:

```
$("a.load").click(function() {
  $.get(this.href, function(result) {
    content = $("<div>").html(result);
    // now content is a new jQuery element to do with as you please
    // it's not in the DOM yet, mind you
    var links = content.find("a");    // maybe you want the resulting links?
    $("#main").append(links);         // maybe you want to add them to the DOM?
  }, "html");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Note: `$("<div>").html(result)` can be done by simply using `$(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to a jQuery call has to be an element, a document or a jQuery-object. You are sending in a string, so it doesn't fit any set of valid parameters. I'm not sure how jQuery reacts to the invalid parameters, but I think that it simply ignores the string and looks for the selector in the current document instead.

Turn the string into elements by sending it to the jQuery function:

```
content = $("#main", $(result));
```

Note that it turns the string into elements by creating a `div` element and set the string as `innerHTML`, so the string has to be an HTML fragment, not a complete HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend using .load() as Dave Ward mentioned.**

If you were to use your own callback in $.get(), you'd need to do something like this (concept is straight out of jQuery source):

```
$("a.load").click(function() {
  $.get(this.href, {}, function(result) {
    var content = $("<div>")
      // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
      // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
      .append(result.responseText.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, ""))
      // Locate the specified elements
      .find("#main").html();

    console.log(content);
  }, "html");
  return false;
});
```